# Write callback function for create custom tooltip content using ng2-charts in angular 13

Tags: angular, ng2-charts, angular13, chart.js3

I want to write a callback function for modifying tooltip's `title` & `label` content on bubble chart generated using `ng2-charts`. I already followed hint from [Custom Tooltip for ng2-charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056450/custom-tooltip-for-ng2-charts) & [Recreating Gapminder using Chart.js](https://www.createwithdata.com/gapminder-chartjs/) but since newest typescript on Angular 13 required to specify any function parameters, the code from those references are not working.

I have read the function's hint to help me specify the required data type for function parameter and figure out one of the data type for `data` (`data: ChartData<'bubble'>`), but still returns error since `tooltipItem` data type is wrong according to the function. Note that forcing the data type as `any` is also not working.

The error message is written below:

```
Error: src/app/bubble-chart/bubble-chart.component.ts:101:11 - error TS2322:
Type '(tooltipItem: TooltipItem<"bubble">[], data: ChartData<"bubble", BubbleDataPoint[], unknown>) => 
string | undefined' is not assignable to type
'(this: TooltipModel<keyof ChartTypeRegistry>, tooltipItems: TooltipItem<keyof ChartTypeRegistry>[]) =>
string | string[]'.

101           title: function (tooltipItem: TooltipItem<'bubble'>[], data: ChartData<'bubble'>) {
```

My current code for modifying bubble chart's tooltip is written bellow:

```js
public bubbleChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        title: function (tooltipItem: TooltipItem<'bubble'>[],
          data: ChartData<'bubble'>) {
            const d = data.datasets[tooltipItem[0].datasetIndex];
            return d.label;
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Just follow the exact signature ?

Comment: What do you mean by exact signature? Is it the way of writing code like 2 example that I provide on the question above?

Comment: I mean your function should follow this signature : `(this: TooltipModel<keyof ChartTypeRegistry>, tooltipItems: TooltipItem<keyof ChartTypeRegistry>[]) =>
string | string[]`

Comment: Unforfunately it's not working since `(this: TooltipModel<keyof ChartTypeRegistry>, tooltipItems: TooltipItem<keyof ChartTypeRegistry>[]) => string | string[]` is general function definition which can be overridden with certain data type.